# Accessing Tomcat directory path

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am working around in a problem where i need to create an upload folder in to tomcat base directory so that can place my upload files there don't want to do this inside the webapps folder.

later on i want to access this folder in my web-application to get that files being uploaded.
though i got success using the below code

```
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "uploads");
```

but its giving me path like
G:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\uploads
from which i can access the files but i want the path something like this

```
http//localhost:// path to my upload folders
```

i tried various way to achieve this but nothing has worked.
i was playing around this but it did't worked out

```
ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getRealPath()
```

can any one give me an idea how i can do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to `/conf/server.xml` of Tomcat:

```
<Context docBase="G:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\uploads" path="/uploads" />
```

It'll be available by http://localhost/uploads

Comment: this means that this will be a hard coded place which can not be changed on run time

Comment: @umesh awasthi, this is the right solution if you don't want to use apache. Also no matter what you use, you have to hardcode the location some where unless you do it using a servlet

Comment: @Teja: agree i will use apache in future not now and than can think of something but rigth now it seems the best solution

Comment: Why would you ever change the upload directory during runtime?

Comment: @Balusc: by that i was mean like if i want to store some data in some other directory so i can pass that path at run time..

Comment: Just create a new directory in `/uploads` folder.

Comment: @umesh awasthi: in future you got to use apache and it should be outside of your tomcat installation as this solution will not work if your prod environment is clustered. so in that case my solution with apache works

Comment: @Teja: that's indeed a more flexible solution. @umesh: that still doesn't allow you to change context path during runtime by the way ;)

Comment: BTW +1 for a competitive answer and for a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

It should typically be the job of your apache server using a alias and virtual directory. If you want it using your application, you have to create your own servlet and get the path of the file and open the file and stream it through the servlet.

Comment: any document or link in this regard will be much helpfull